# When i modified the selected date of the CalendarView I got a negative month and 31+ days in month

Tags: java, android, calendar

i try to get a previous date of custom date that selected by a user but i cant find a way to do that
this is the code

```
 calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange( @NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth ) {
                finalDate = (dayOfMonth + 7) + "/" + (month - 3) + "/" + year;

                try {
                    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(finalDate);


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

so if i select 30/2/2020 the result is : (37/-1/2020)

Comment: Please, what had you expected? 30 + 7 equals 37, and 2 - 3 equals -1. And possibly a different question, what behaviour had you wanted/desired? Also in general, always when asking about code that doesn’t behave the way you wanted it to, be specific about expected behaviour and how observed behaviour differs. Then it’s much easier to help you. As your question stands, I don’t think I can, sorry

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. Not least when you need to math on dates. I frankly find it much better suited than the old and outdated `Calendar` class, not to mention `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
    int year = 2020;
    int month = Calendar.MARCH; // For demonstration only, don’t use Calendar in your code
    int dayOfMonth = 30;
    
    LocalDate selectedDate = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
    LocalDate finalDate = selectedDate.minusMonths(3).plusDays(7);
    
    System.out.println(finalDate);
```

Output:

> 2020-01-06

I believe that your Android date picker numbers months from 0 for January through 11 for December, so we need to add 1 to convert to the natural way that humans and `LocalDate` number months. When we start out from 30th March, we subtract 3 months and get 30th December, then add 7 days and get 6th January. We might also have done the math in the opposite order:

```
    LocalDate finalDate = selectedDate.plusDays(7).minusMonths(3);
```

In this case it gave the same result, but since months have unequal lengths, it won’t always.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you are adding 7 to your day count and subtracting 3 from your month count? Try removing that and it should work better.

Comment: It seems clear from the question that they are trying to add 7 to the day and subtract 3 from the month, and _get a valid date_, so not doing the thing they're trying to do isn't going to help.